# outer measure is a measure?

Tags: measure-theory, outer-measure

Let $\alpha$ be an outer measure on $\mathcal P(\mathbb R^d)$, with the property that for every $A,B\subseteq \mathbb R^d$ with $A\cap B=\emptyset \Rightarrow \alpha(A\cup B)=\alpha(A)+\alpha(B)$.

Is $\alpha$ a measure on $\mathcal P(\mathbb R^d)$? I think yes.
By induction I can show that $A_1,\dots,A_n$ disjoint, then $\alpha(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha(A_i)$ but this works only for a finite number of sets.

Comment: [A finitely additive measure on $\Bbb{R}$ which is not sigma-additive?](https://mathoverflow.net/a/313222/483536)

Comment: I agree with @SouravGhosh ... but, despite having a good answer, this question cannot be marked as a duplicate of that (since the answer is not accepted, I guess).

Comment: There is no need to duplicate the existing question.